# Change a column name according to the file name

Tags: bash

I have around 52 files named like: `ERR260147.genefamilies.tsv, ERR260158.genefamilies.tsv ERR275198.genefamilies.tsv, etc` and each file has two columns. I want to change the second column name of each file according to the name of the file.
For example, the second column name for file `ERR260147.genefamilies.tsv` will be named like `ERR260147_Abundance-RPKs` and for `ERR275198.genefamilies.tsv` will be `ERR275198_Abundance-RPKs`. Please note, part of a column name will come from the file name and a constant **"_Abundance-RPKs"**.

Please help me. I am naive in Linux.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are using Ubuntu GNOME. Open the folder location, select all those 52 files, right click and select rename.

Select the option of `Find and replace text`, and in the `Existing Text` type `.genefamilies.tsv` and in the `Replace With` type `_Abundance-RPKs`, and then click rename button.

[image]

You can also preview before renaming the files

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, in awk

```
awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} FNR==1 {split(FILENAME,a,/\./); $2 = a[1] "_Abundance-RPKs"} 1' *.genefamilies.tsv
```

If you have a recent version of GNU awk (aka `gawk`), then once you are comfortable that it is doing the right thing you can apply the change in-place ex. given

```
$ head *.genefamilies.tsv
==> ERR260147.genefamilies.tsv <==
foo     bar
123     456
abc     def

==> ERR260158.genefamilies.tsv <==
foo     bar
123     456
abc     def

==> ERR275198.genefamilies.tsv <==
foo     bar
123     456
abc     def
```

then

```
gawk -i inplace -F'\t' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} FNR==1 {split(FILENAME,a,/\./); $2 = a[1] "_Abundance-RPKs"} 1' *.genefamilies.tsv
```

results in

```
$ head *.genefamilies.tsv                                                                                                        ==> ERR260147.genefamilies.tsv <==
foo     ERR260147_Abundance-RPKs
123     456
abc     def

==> ERR260158.genefamilies.tsv <==
foo     ERR260158_Abundance-RPKs
123     456
abc     def

==> ERR275198.genefamilies.tsv <==
foo     ERR275198_Abundance-RPKs
123     456
abc     def
```